# fetched data is not displayed in React

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the data from this API

```
https://covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/v1/total
```

The data is successfully displayed in the console
but it is not displayed in the browser

```
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState('USA');
  const [stats, setStats] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(API_URL, {
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-coronavirus-statistics.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        },
        params: {
          country: selectedCountry
        }
      });

      setStats(result.data.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [selectedCountry]);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-4">
    <div className="select w-full md:w-1/2">
      <h2 className="text-xl text-red-600 font-medium mb-3">Select a Country:</h2>
      <select value={selectedCountry} onChange={e => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)} className="block appearance-none w-full bg-white text-blue-500 border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
        {countries.map(country => (
          <option key={country} value={country}>{country}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
    <div className="stats w-full text-blue-600 md:w-1/2 mt-4">
      <h2 className="text-xl text-red-600 font-medium mb-3">Selected Country:</h2>
      <h2 className='text-yellow-600 mb-4 bg-gray-200'>{selectedCountry}</h2> 
      <p className="stat">Confirmed Cases: {stats.confirmed}</p>
      <p className="stat">Deaths: {stats.deaths}</p>
      <p className="stat">Recoveries: {stats.recovered}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the result in the console is:

```
: 
confirmed
: 
4563190
deaths
: 
50541
lastChecked
: 
"2023-01-31T18:11:16+00:00"
lastReported
: 
"2023-01-31T04:20:32+00:00"
location
: 
"US"
recovered
: 
null
```

also, I share the image:

[image]

Note that I've already used my own API key

Comment: Where is the `console.log`? Could you please show what the data looks like?

Comment: Don't put that in a comment, [put those missing details in your post please](/help/how-to-ask). Also, "supposed" isn't good enough: what are you _actually_ seeing. And on a sidenote: why declare a const function and then invoke it when you're already passing a function to useEffect? just make _that_ an `async` arrow function and run the code you need directly.

Comment: @Konrad i have edited my question and added the result

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok i will try to do it
but the problem isnt in this part of the code
i guess it is in the retrun

Comment: Again, don't talk about what things are "supposed" to be: show us what they _are_ by showing that console.log, and copy-pasting what your console shows you that is. In order to understand what's wrong, we need to see what you're seeing, not what you're _supposed_ to see.

Comment: `fetchData` is async and you don't await it.

Comment: That is definitely not a copy-paste of what the console shows, though.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i dont know what is your problem with me
im not here to lie neither to provide false infos
Iam here looking for help
i have added a photo of what iam getting :D

Comment: Yes, so: notice that screenshot is an object, whereas what you've put in your post is a mangled string: copy the object (you may need to JSON.stringify it) and then put it in your post as the actual object code. This matters, because you're asking for technical help with programming. Details matter _a lot_. If you get an object back, show that object, using the notation for objects, so that the people you're asking for help can see the actual data you're working with.

Comment: so after all you couldnt at least provide me an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows blank screen which means your dev server is not rendering anything. you have a different error, check your console.

[image]

If you did not have any error on console, You would at least get this html without data values. (I styled values to red)

in your code you have `countries.map`. you might have "Uncaught ReferenceError: countries is not defined". Just like this: blank screen with console errors

[image]